# Sums with k dice

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I have n dice, each with k sides, numbered from 1 to k inclusive. I want to find in how many ways I can get a sum of x using those dice.

Doing some research, I found that what I am looking for is called a composition of x. The formula for the number of compositions of x is pretty straightforward, but not all compositions are accepted by the problem statement (I should count only those with elements smaller or equal to k).

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: Does it matter which die gives you which number? That is, if $n = 2$, $k = 6$, and $x = 7$, do you count $(1,6)$ and $(6,1)$ as two different ways to get the sum, or does this only count as one way?

Comment: The number of ways to get the sum $r$ is the coefficient of $x^r$ in $(1+x+\cdots+x^k)^n$, and that can be evaluated by the Binomial Theorem. The question has been asked and answered many times on this website (although it's not so easy to find --- but try looking at the problems listed under the "Related" heading).

Comment: The exact answer is not pleasant to calculate. For medium to large $n$, approximating by a normal is useful.

Comment: @DavidK: Yes, (1, 6) and (6, 1) are 2 different ways.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: That seems to be the correct answer, thank you. I shall search more deeply for a proof.

Comment: I should have written $(x+x^2+\cdots+x^k)^n$, since the dice are numbered $1$ to $k$, not zero to $k$.